# View list of sudoers with no sudo privileges

Tags: permissions, sudo, group

- If I'm not a sudoer, is it possible to view the list of sudoers?
- Does `/etc/group` show this information?

Comment: Well, if a user is in the `wheel` group, that is often a give-away, but it's not guaranteed. I do not believe `/etc/group` contains any information specific to the sudoers.

Comment: The sudoers information is in neither /etc/group nor /etc/passwd. It is in /etc/sudoers and /etc/sudoers.d/* but those files are typically readable only by root.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No you're unable to find out whom has access to sudo rights if you yourself do not have access directly. You could possibly "back into it" by seeing what users if any are members of the Unix group "wheel".

#### Example

This shows that user "saml" is a member of the wheel group.

```
$ getent group wheel
wheel:x:10:saml
```

Being a member of the "wheel" group typically allows for full sudo rights through this rule that's often in a systems sudoers file, `/etc/sudoers`.

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)   ALL
```

But there are no guarantees that the administrator of a given system decided to give `sudo` rights out in this manner. The just as easily could've done it like so:

```
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere 
root    ALL=(ALL)   ALL
saml    ALL=(ALL)   ALL
```

In which case, without `sudo` rights you could never gain access to a system's `/etc/sudoers` file to see this entry.

#### What about /etc/groups

This file only shows users who have a 2nd, 3rd, etc. group associated with them. Often times user accounts only have a single group associated, in which case you'd need to use a slightly different command to find out a given user's primary group:

```
$ getent passwd saml
saml:x:1000:1000:saml:/home/saml:/bin/bash
```

Here user "saml" has the primary group 1000. This GID equates to this group:

```
$ getent group 1000
saml:x:1000:saml
```

But none of this actually tells you anything as to which user accounts have `sudo` rights.

#### Why the big secret?

This is all done to prevent what's known as a [side channel attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_channel_attack). Leaking information out, such as which accounts have privileges, would give important information out to a would be attacker, if they were able to gain access to any account on a given system. So often times it's best to mask this info from any non-privileged account.